# Oracle cloud - Connect to Windows instance with disabled ethernet

Tags: windows, networking, oracle

As I was troubleshooting the network connection of my Windows instance, I managed to disable the OCI Ethernet adapter, which makes it impossible to connect to the instance through RDP. I've have literally zero experience with Oracle Cloud, and I'm looking for a similar solution as VMware VSphere which makes it possible to connect to a "offline" instance, or just re-enable the Ethernet adapter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using following blog: [Simple console connections for Windows administrators](https://blogs.oracle.com/cloud-infrastructure/post/simple-console-connections-for-windows-administrators)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

... which you will have to do. Through orcale support or the OOB console.